# TortoiseGitProc command line parameters for showcompare command

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Does anyone know full list of command line parameters for command: `TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:showcompare`. I don't know how to pass two revisions to compare. There is no info in [help file](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-automation.html).

Comment: Why not ask the developers? - In the meantime this information was added in the help file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in [that diff](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/source/diff?spec=svnbd9674316d8bb5eccfecfc772b9a7478477f9fcf&r=332aaaa7769768da66bf4019cd09754d28fd6a3c&format=side&path=/src/TortoiseProc/Commands/ShowCompareCommand.cpp) the expected parameters

```
if (parser.HasVal(_T("revision1")))
    rev1 = SVNRev(parser.GetVal(_T("revision1")));  32  rev1 = parser.GetVal(_T("revision1"));
if (parser.HasVal(_T("revision2")))     33  if (parser.HasVal(_T("revision2")))
    rev2 = SVNRev(parser.GetVal(_T("revision2")));  34  rev2 = parser.GetVal(_T("revision2"));
```

It should be used as [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/ligaz/8711120):

```
tgit showcompare /revision1:$($commits[-1]) /revision2:$($commits[0])
```

For example, when used directly in command-line in a repo (as opposed to the above example, which is part of a script):

```
TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:showcompare /revision1:HEAD /revision2:HEAD~
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Next time I'll remember to check source code :)